# In Anylogic, how to send a ressource to the closest agent?

Tags: anylogic

My goal is to simulate a dual cycling process in a terminal. That is to say that when a Tractor drops a container on the terminal, it should pick another one to bring it back into the vessel.

I have two type of agents (named Import container and Export container) that are processed in two different flows. The flow 1 represent the deloading of a vessel and only deals with "Inport Container". The flow 2 represents the loading procces and only deal with "Export Container". Both flows are Seizing the same resource ("Tractor") to move the container. There is then one Seize block per flow.

When a resource "Tractor" is released, is it possible to send it to the closest agent (either "Export Container" or "Import Container") that is waiting in one of the two Seize block?

Because so far, the Tractors are going randomly to an Import Container or to an Export Container.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible via customize resource choice on the seize blocks and customize request choice on the resource pool to get the behavior you desire most of the time.  However, I would recommend you re-architect your model to have your tractor be the "driver entity" or in other words make your model more "agent based".  With the pure flow chart architecture you have, you will likely continue to run into challenges and struggle to get your model complete.

Let the containers that need to be moved site in a detached queue or just reside on the list.  The tractor should loop through logic - either state charts or process blocks, to decide what items it wants to work on next.  The tractor will pick a work item, delay to move it, and then pick its next work item.  If the tractor has nothing to work on, it can go into a waiting state (or detached queue).  Once there is new work or some other condition, call code to wake the tractor up and have it re-evaluate what it wants to work on.

Comment: Thank Amy, we will consider this new architecture !